# Was wearing the Ephod allowed inside Kodesh Hakodashim?

Tags: halacha, beis-hamikdash, kohen-gadol, temple-service-avoda

Was the use of the Ephod allowed inside the temple in the Sanctum Sanctorum?

Comment: first thing that comes to mind when you say "sanctum sanctorum" is doctor strange, not the kodesh hakedoshim lol. very archaic terminology there! it's usually referred to as the "holy of holies" in english.

Comment: If you mean the Holy of Holies, it was only used for worship by the Kohen Gadol on Yom Kippur. And when he did so, he wore only plain linen garments. As the Ephod was made of a blend including colorful wools, then the answer is no.

Comment: please clarify your concerns.

Comment: @Shalom if repairs need to be done and the Kohen Gadol is the most handy person available, is he allowed to wear the gold clothing in to do them?  (I don't know why he'd want to... maybe if there's something urgent that has to be done on Erev Pesach and he wants to wear the tzitz according to the opinion that it's only meratzeh if he's wearing it.)